# How do i show Last seven days of a week from current date in area spline categories highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to show last seven days of a week from the current date in area spline highchart xaxis categories. I tried more but none is working. Please help me if anyone knows.

I tried the following code in area spline highcharts.

```
xAxis: {      
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600000,
    min: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 29),
    max: Date.UTC(2019, 2, 4),   
    labels: {           
        style: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontFamily: 'Honeywell Sans',
            fontSize: '11px'
        },
        format: '{value:%b-%e}'
    }
```

This code is not working for my requirement.

Comment: Hi user2703151, Could you provide us with a more detailed description of the problem? Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9er6xwqg/, the 7-days range is achieved by `min` and `max` properties.

Answer (score -1):

Will this answer be of any help.

[How to set weekly range in X Axis of High Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739200/how-to-set-weekly-range-in-x-axis-of-high-chart)

Sorry for putting this in answers , i do not have enough credits to add comment.